# matching and recording in R

Tags: r, matching

I have a data frame like this, called `df`:

```
a  b  c  d  e  f  
b  c  f  a  a  a  
d  f  a  b  c  c  
f  e  d  f  f  d
```

The first row is actually the column name. Let's take an example to explain the meaning here: `df[1,1]` is `b`, which means there is relation from `a` to `b`, so the values in the column means there is relation from the 'column name' to that entry.
I want create a `matrix(df1)` with 6*6 dimension, column and row names are both column names of `df`. The (i,j) entry is 1, if there is relation from 'i' to 'j', otherwise, 0.

The output I want is:

```
    a  b  c  d  e  f
a   0  1  0  1  0  1
b   0  0  1  0  1  1
c   1  0  0  1  0  1
d   1  1  0  0  0  1
e   1  0  1  0  0  1
f   1  0  1  1  0  0
```

How to do this with a loop in R?
How to do this without a loop, and only use basic R?
How to do this using some fancy packages in R?

Comment: Yes, but how to post my data..using link?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93744/discussion-between-white-big-and-pascal).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the reshape2 package, this is one way to go. My sample data has all columns as character. You use `melt()` to reshape your data in a long format. Then, you use `dcast()` from the same package.

```
library(magrittr)
library(reshape2)

melt(mydf, measure.vars = names(mydf)) %>%
dcast(variable ~ value, length)

  variable a b c d e f
1        a 0 1 0 1 0 1
2        b 0 0 1 0 1 1
3        c 1 0 0 1 0 1
4        d 1 1 0 0 0 1
5        e 1 0 1 0 0 1
6        f 1 0 1 1 0 0
```

**EDIT**
As mentioned below by akrun, you can do all work using `recast()` in the reshape2 package.

```
recast(mydf, measure.var= names(mydf),variable~value, length)
```

**DATA**

```
mydf <- structure(list(a = c("b", "d", "f"), b = c("c", "f", "e"), c = c("f", 
"a", "d"), d = c("a", "b", "f"), e = c("a", "c", "f"), f = c("a", 
"c", "d")), .Names = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: You could also use `recast` in one step `recast(mydf, measure.var= names(mydf),variable~value, length)`

Comment: @akrun All right. I want to check that function now. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: It is just a wrapper for `melt/dcast`, nothing more.

Comment: @akrun I see. That one liner is the winner.

Comment: @White.Big Pleasure. :)

Comment: You can also do this in one line using base R `table` calls. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `table`:

```
table(colnames(mydf)[col(mydf)], unlist(mydf) )

#    a b c d e f
#  a 0 1 0 1 0 1
#  b 0 0 1 0 1 1
#  c 1 0 0 1 0 1
#  d 1 1 0 0 0 1
#  e 1 0 1 0 0 1
#  f 1 0 1 1 0 0
```

If you have multiple matches, then:

```
pmin(table(colnames(mydf)[col(mydf)], unlist(mydf) ), 1)
```

Comment: That is a great base R solution. +1

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with reshaping.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  gather(from, to) %>%
  distinct %>%
  mutate(value = 1) %>%
  spread(to, value, fill = 0)
```

Comment: Reshaping is really difficult to explain without running things and seeing what they do. The tidyr vignette is here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html

Answer (score 0):

The other solution using `dplyr` is really neat and smart. I recommend using that solution.

Here is an alternative solution to your problem using most basic functions in R.

Say your data frame has `n` columns and `m` rows i.e. `n <- ncol(df)` and `m <- nrow(df)`.

```
output_matrix <- matrix(rep(0, n*n), ncol = n)
for(i in 1:n){
    for(j in 1:m){
        # UTF to integer conversion
        # utf8ToInt("a") = 97
        rowWithRelation <- utf8ToInt(df[j, i]) - 96
        output_matrix[rowWithRelation, i] <- 1
    }
}
rownames(output_matrix) <- letters[seq(from = 1, to = n)]
colnames(output_matrix) <- letters[seq(from = 1, to = n)]
```